# Characterising inverses of $g'\in G'$ with the right cosets of $\ker \phi$ where $\phi:G\to G'$ is a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

> $\phi: G\to G'$ is a homomorphism, with $\ker\phi = K$. The set of all inverse images of $g'\in G'$ under $\phi$ in $G$ is given by $Kx$, where $x$ is any particular inverse image of $g'\in G'$, under $\phi$.

**My work:**
Let $e,e'$ be the identity elements in $G,G'$ respectively. Let $x_0$ be a particular inverse image of $g'$, i.e. $\phi(x_0) = g'$. By definition, $K = \{x\in G: \phi(x) = e'\}$. Consider two sets, $Kx_0$ and $S$, where:
$$Kx_0 = \{kx_0: k\in K\}$$
$$S = \{x\in G: \phi(x) = g'\}$$
First we show $Kx_0 \subseteq S$. This is easy! Take $kx_0 \in Kx_0$ for some $k\in K$. Note that $\phi(kx_0) = \phi(k)\phi(x_0) = e'g' = g'$. So, $kx_0\in S$. This direction is done.

I am slightly suspicious of my proof of $S\subseteq Kx_0$. I take $x\in S$, so $\phi(x) = g'$.
$$g' = \phi(x) = \phi(x_0) = e'\phi(x_0) =  \phi(k)\phi(x_0) = \phi(kx_0)$$ for some $k\in K$. Now, $x = kx_0$ certainly satisfies the above equality (though there may be other possibilities). So, $x\in Kx_0$.

Is this last step correct? If yes, how do I make it more rigorous? If not, please suggest alternatives/improvements. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is not correct. Starting with $x \in S$, you must show that $x \in Kx_0$. All you have done is shown that "it's possible" for that to happen. What you have to actually do is show that that *must* happen.

Here's how you can prove $S \subseteq Kx_0$. Let $x \in S$. Then, $\phi(x) = g' = \phi(x_0)$ and hence,
$$e' = \phi(x)\phi(x_0)^{-1} = \phi(xx_0^{-1})$$
and hence, $xx_0^{-1} \in \ker \phi = K$. This finishes the proof.

Comment: Nice proof! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in\phi^{\leftarrow}(\{g'\})$. Then:

\begin{alignat}{1}
Kx &= \{gx\in G\mid \phi(g)=e'\} \\
&= \{y\in G\mid \phi(yx^{-1})=e'\} \\
&= \{y\in G\mid \phi(y)\phi(x)^{-1}=e'\} \\
&= \{y\in G\mid \phi(y)=\phi(x)\} \\
&= \varphi^{\leftarrow}(\{\phi(x)\}) \\
&= \varphi^{\leftarrow}(\{g'\}) \\
\end{alignat}

Comment: Thanks! I'm more used to $\phi^{-1}$ than $\phi^{\leftarrow}$ - but thanks for introducing me to this notation.

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine, yes I know "$\phi^{-1}$" is widely used, but I believe it's tricky becasue it may mislead to thinking that $\phi$ is invertible, which may not be the case. However, that's fine as long as it is clear.